# How to extract facebook page replies into a website?

Tags: api, wordpress, facebook, rss, blogs

I've got a facebook page.  In it there is the RSS feed of posts from my blog.  In the facebook page people have replied to my blog posts that where posted on facebook.

Now I wish to show these replies on my blog.

Is there any way for doing that?

Answer (score 1):

If you have done it with the notes function of Facebook, there is a plugin for WordpPress doing exactly what you need: [Facebook Comments](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-comments/)

Comment: Thank you Kau,
 wonderful answer. Except that this plugin doesn't work for WP 2.9.2  :(

Comment: have you tried search within you wp-admin for a plugin? Maybe there is no plugin for newer versions of WordPress. Or maybe Facebook has changed something so it doesn't work again. If I had the time, I would try to fix the plugin.

Comment: The latest update was 10 months ago, see here: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/251461?replies=5

Comment: I searched 2 other such plugins - and I see both are not working anymore. What a shame...